# Label a polygon

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, polygon

[image]I have a function that I use to createan array of points, so I can draw a polygon, I want to label inside of this polygons, I know it can be done using drawstring or label control, but I want to make sure I have the same orientation of the polygon in my case they are rectangles also control the font size depend on the shape size.

I tried to create a rect inside the Draw string didn't work, any Ideas

```
 private void BuildImage()
    {
        Graphics refGraph = this.CreateGraphics();
        IntPtr hdc = refGraph.GetHdc();
        Metafile image = new Metafile(hdc, EmfType.EmfOnly, "Shapes");
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 0.2f);
            foreach (CircuitData.ResistorRow resistorRow in ResistorData.Resistor)
            {
                RectangleF rec = new RectangleF((float)(resistorRow.CenterX - resistorRow.Length / 2), (float)(resistorRow.CenterY - resistorRow.Width / 2), (float)resistorRow.Length, (float)resistorRow.Width);
                float orientation = 360 - (float)resistorRow.Orientation;
                PointF center = new PointF((float)resistorRow.CenterX, (float)resistorRow.CenterY);
                PointF[] points = CreatePolygon(rec, center, orientation);
                if (!Double.IsNaN(resistorRow.HiX) && !Double.IsNaN(resistorRow.HiY))
                {
                    g.FillEllipse(myBrush, (float)resistorRow.HiX - 0.5f, (float)resistorRow.HiY - 0.5f, 1, 1);
                    g.DrawLine(p, new PointF((float)resistorRow.HiX, (float)resistorRow.HiY), center);
                }

                g.FillPolygon(myBrush, points);

                Font drawFont = new Font("cursor", 1);
                SolidBrush textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
                //g.Transform = matrix;
                g.DrawString(resistorRow.ComponentName, drawFont, textBrush, points[0]);
            }
        }
        refGraph.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
        refGraph.Dispose();
        Image = image;

    }


private PointF[] CreatePolygon(RectangleF rec, PointF center, float orientation)
        {
            PointF TL = new PointF(rec.Left, rec.Top);
            PointF TR = new PointF(rec.Right, rec.Top);
            PointF BL = new PointF(rec.Left, rec.Bottom);
            PointF BR = new PointF(rec.Right, rec.Bottom);
            PointF[] points = new PointF[] { BL, TL, TR, BR, BL };
            matrix = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix();
            matrix.RotateAt(orientation, center);
            matrix.TransformPoints(points);
            return points;
        }
```

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you use WPF for this instead of winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply your rotation matrix to the graphic context you're working with:

```
        e.Graphics.Transform = matrix;
        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(textBrush, points);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(resistorRow.ComponentName, drawFont, textBrush2, TL);
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Some ***sample*** code:

```
public class ResistorWithLabel
{
    public string ComponentName { get; set; }
    public RectangleF Rect { get; set; }
    public float Orientation { get; set; }
    public Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public Color ForegroundColor { get; set; }
    public int FontSize { get; set; }

    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        Matrix contextMatrix = g.Transform;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.RotateAt(Orientation, new PointF((Rect.Left+Rect.Right)/2, (Rect.Top+Rect.Bottom)/2));

        SolidBrush polygonBrush = new SolidBrush(BackgroundColor);
        SolidBrush textBrush = new SolidBrush(ForegroundColor);
        Font font = new Font("Courier", FontSize);

        PointF TL = new PointF(Rect.Left, Rect.Top);
        PointF TR = new PointF(Rect.Right, Rect.Top);
        PointF BL = new PointF(Rect.Left, Rect.Bottom);
        PointF BR = new PointF(Rect.Right, Rect.Bottom);
        PointF[] points = new PointF[] { BL, TL, TR, BR };

        g.Transform = matrix;
        g.FillPolygon(polygonBrush, points);
        g.DrawString(ComponentName, font, textBrush, TL);
        g.Transform = contextMatrix;
    }
}

    private void Form3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        ResistorWithLabel r1 = new ResistorWithLabel();
        r1.ComponentName = "Resistor 1";
        r1.Rect = new RectangleF(50, 100, 100, 50);
        r1.Orientation = 25;
        r1.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
        r1.ForegroundColor = Color.Yellow;
        r1.FontSize = 16;
        r1.Draw(e.Graphics);

        ResistorWithLabel r2 = new ResistorWithLabel();
        r2.ComponentName = "Resistor 2";
        r2.Rect = new RectangleF(200, 100, 200, 100);
        r2.Orientation = 75;
        r2.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray;
        r2.ForegroundColor = Color.Orange;
        r2.FontSize = 32;
        r2.Draw(e.Graphics);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I didnt work for me.I will update my code, maybe I'm doing something wrong, my polygon are already transformed when i;m trying to transform the string only my entire shapes sequence get screw up

Comment: When I did put g.tranform = matrix before my DrawString my strings went all over the place. I updated the code for you also my Polygon changed positions

Comment: You can't just do that blindly.... You asked for "any ideas"... The idea here is that your code, as it is, applies the rotation matrix only to the rectangle but not the string. So, you have to apply to both.